# mooTools Binding All Classes

Tags: mootools

I am not used to using mooTools, it looks a lot like Prototype JS. Can anyone tell me how to bind this to every class?

```
// This grabs all the classes
var mousy = $$('.hf-item-images');

// I don't think this is correct to apply this scroller to all the above classes
var scroll = new Scroller(mousy, {area: 100, velocity: 1});

// Mousemove
mousy.addEvent('mouseover', scroll.start.bind(scroll));
mousy.addEvent('mouseout', scroll.stop.bind(scroll));
```

Comment: This is indeed incorrect: `var scroll = new Scroller(mousy, {area: 100, velocity: 1});` - the Scroller constructor exepts single element: [Scroller](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Scroller) - what are you trying to do it's not clear - if you want to apply all mousy elements to be a scroller just build a simple class to do that- you will need to call Scroller for each element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to be smarter about this, looping through nnnn items to make scollers can be expensive. so is attaching pairs of events on each one.

given markup like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="hf-item-images">...</div>
    <div class="hf-item-images">...</div>
</div>
```

you can delegate stuff on the parent and only instantiate a scroller instance on elements that need it, reusing it afterwards.

```
var container = document.id('container'),
    settings = {
        area: 100,
        velocity: 1
    };

container.addEvents({
    'mouseover:relay(.hf-item-images)': function(e, el){
        var scroll = el.retrieve('scroller');
        if (!scroll){
            // create instance the first mouseenter and store for later
            scroll = new Scroller(el, settings);
            el.store('scroller', scroll);
        }
        scroll.start();
    },
    'mouseout:relay(.hf-item-images)': function(e, el){
        el.retrieve('scroller').stop();
    }
});
```